# Update multiple records in single UPDATE request

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to update multiple records' balances based on each record's Currency Code in a Currency table, something to the effect of this:

```
UPDATE Currency
SET `Balance` = `Balance` - NEW.AmountOut WHERE `CurrencyCode` = ?,
    `Balance` = `Balance` + NEW.AmountIn - NEW.Commission WHERE `CurrencyCode` = ?;
```

I'm sure you see the logic but my implementation seems to be a little messed up. Where am I going wrong and what's the solution?

Comment: use case when  statement to update columns based on condition.

Comment: Will try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `case when` example

```
update Currency
set Balance= case when CurrencyCode= ? then `Balance` - NEW.AmountOut
 else `Balance` + NEW.AmountIn - NEW.Commission end
```